# Geolocation apis supports IPv6 enviornment

Tags: ios, xcode, google-api, location, ipv6

In my iOS app I am using googleapis for fetching user current location.

I want to know whether googleapis support IPv6 environment.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably downvoted because this was trivially easy to find out.

```
$ host www.googleapis.com
www.googleapis.com is an alias for googleapis.l.google.com.
googleapis.l.google.COM has address 74.125.29.95
googleapis.l.google.COM has address 173.194.206.95
googleapis.l.google.COM has address 173.194.205.95
googleapis.l.google.COM has address 74.125.22.95
googleapis.l.google.COM has address 173.194.68.95
googleapis.l.google.COM has address 209.85.232.95
googleapis.l.google.COM has IPv6 address 2607:f8b0:400d:c0d::5f
```

So, yes, it supports IPv6.